# python-ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python

I generate a random sample from the two dimensional distribution, But I got this run time error. Could someone tell me how to fix this error? 
This is the error message:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     25     # Do the accept/reject comparison
     26     if x < P(x,y):
---> 27         samples[accepted] = x,y
     28         accepted += 1
     29

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
P = lambda x, y: np.exp(-x**2-y**2-x**2*y**2)

# domain limits
xmin = -2 # the lower limit of our domain
xmax = 2 # the upper limit of our domain

# range limit (supremum) for y
ymin = -2
ymax = 2

N = 10000 # the total of samples we wish to generate
accepted = 0 # the number of accepted samples
samples = np.zeros(N)
count = 0 # the total count of proposals

# generation loop
while (accepted < N):

    # pick a uniform number on [xmin, xmax) (e.g. 0...10)
    x = np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax)

    # pick a uniform number on [0, ymax)
    y = np.random.uniform(ymin,ymax)

    # Do the accept/reject comparison
    if x < P(x,y):
        samples[accepted] = x,y
        accepted += 1

    count +=1

print count, accepted

# get the histogram info
hinfo = np.histogram(samples,30)

# plot the histogram
plt.hist(samples,bins=30, label=u'Samples', alpha=0.5);

# plot our (normalized) function
xvals=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)
plt.plot(xvals, hinfo[0][0]*P(xvals), 'r', label=u'P(x)')

# turn on the legend
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The line here:

```
samples[accepted] = x,y
```

is the problem. `samples` is of type np.ndarray with a specific `dtype`. Probably `np.float`. `numpy` is expecting a single number but getting a `tuple(x,y)`. Probably you meant to create a 2D array:

```
samples = np.zeros((N,2))
```

Then your code should work, though I haven't looked deeper into what it all is actually trying to do.

### An Aside

I see you are looping over `N` while generating numbers. This is typical of someone just picking up numpy/scipy from another programming language. I would like to urge you to "think in arrays". This is far more elegant and much much faster:

```
x = np.random.uniform(xmin,xmax,(N,2))
y = np.random.uniform(ymin,ymax,(N,2))
accepted = x < P(x,y)
samples[accepted] = x[accepted]
```

The above code replaces your entire `while` loop.